# Issue in jasmine unit test in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
var a, b = [];
a = false;

[
 var1: a,
 arrayVal: b
].forEach(function (scenario) {
  scenario.var1 = true;
  scenario.arrayVal.push("1", "2");
});

it("results", function () {
  expect(a).toBe(true);// 1st test
  expect(b).toEqual(["1", "2"]); // 2nd test
});
```

In the above code,
2nd test success,
1st test fails, saying "expected false to be true"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a mistake in your code. You are treating an array like an object by assigning values to var1 and arrayVal. The foreach statement should look like:

```
[{
  var1: a, 
  arrayVal: b
}].forEach(function (scenario) {
    scenario.var1 = true;
    scenario.arrayVal.push("1", "2");   
});
```

In regards to why your first test is failing, this is because you're replacing the entire value and reference of 'a', whereas with 'arrayVal' you are manipulating the current value by pushing values into the array. Here is a code example:

```
var a = [true];
var var1;

//expecting... a: [true], var1: undefined
console.log('a: ' + a + ' var1: ' + var1);
var1 = a; 

//expecting... a: [true], var1: [true]
console.log('a: ' + a + ' var1: ' + var1); 

//manipulating the reference of a affects var1
a.push([false]); 

//expecting... a: [true, false], var1: [true, false]
console.log('a: ' + a + ' var1: ' + var1);

//replacing the value of a does not affect var1
a = [true]; 

//expecting... a: [true], var1: [true, false]
console.log('a: ' + a + ' var1: ' + var1);
```

Also note that booleans are primary (primitive) data types and you can't reference a value from 2 properties. Arrays and objects are composite data types, which means that multiple properties can reference a value.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I don't want "a" to be declared as Array/object, it should be declared as variable/boolean.

Comment: Well then you're in a bit of a pickle. What are you trying to achieve with this test?